# How to update the version of Box2D used in AndEngine?

Tags: java, box2d, andengine, physics-engine

I need help to use an updated Box2D library where the current version is > 2.3.0. I am unable to find a compatible library and do not know how to compile one for use with the Java Native Interface (JNI).

Comment: Looks like they copied and modified the source of libgdx box2d extension. This makes it extremely hard to port (to a newer version). I have a Java box2d binding for 2.4.1, based on the libgdx one (so not andengine)